# Finetuning LayoutLM on FUNSD-like dataset - index out of range in self

Tags: neural-network, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm experimenting with `huggingface` transformers to finetune `microsoft/layoutlmv2-base-uncased` through `AutoModelForTokenClassification` on my custom dataset that is similar to FUNSD (pre-processed and normalized). After a few iterations of training I get this error :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "layoutlmV2/train.py", line 137, in <module>
    trainer.train()
  File "..../lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1409, in train
    return inner_training_loop(
  File "..../lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1651, in _inner_training_loop
    tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
  File "..../lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 2345, in training_step
    loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
  File "..../lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 2377, in compute_loss
    outputs = model(**inputs)
  File "..../lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1131, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "..../lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/layoutlmv2/modeling_layoutlmv2.py", line 1228, in forward
    outputs = self.layoutlmv2(
  File "..../lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1131, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "..../lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/layoutlmv2/modeling_layoutlmv2.py", line 902, in forward
    text_layout_emb = self._calc_text_embeddings(
  File "..../lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/layoutlmv2/modeling_layoutlmv2.py", line 753, in _calc_text_embeddings
    spatial_position_embeddings = self.embeddings._calc_spatial_position_embeddings(bbox)
  File "..../lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/layoutlmv2/modeling_layoutlmv2.py", line 93, in _calc_spatial_position_embeddings
    h_position_embeddings = self.h_position_embeddings(bbox[:, :, 3] - bbox[:, :, 1])
  File "..../lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1131, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "..../lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py", line 158, in forward
    return F.embedding(
  File "..../lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2203, in embedding
    return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
IndexError: index out of range in self
```

After further inspection (vocab size, bboxes, dimensions, classes...) I noticed that there's negative values inside the input tensor causing the error. While input tensors of successful previous iterations have unsigned integers only. These negative numbers are returned by `_calc_spatial_position_embeddings(self, bbox)` in `modeling_layoutlmv2.py`

line 92 :

```
h_position_embeddings = self.h_position_embeddings(bbox[:, :, 3] - bbox[:, :, 1])
```

- What may cause the returned input values to be negative?
- What could I do to prevent this error from happening?

---

*Example of the input tensor that triggers the error in `torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)` :*

```
tensor([[ 0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,
         11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,
         11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,
         11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11,
         11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,
          9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
         12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
         12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
         12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
         12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
         12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11,
         11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
         12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12,
         12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,
         11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,
         11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,
         10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12,
         12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
         12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
         12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
         12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,
         11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,
         11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,
         11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
         12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,
          8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,
          8,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5, -6, -6, -6, -6, -6, -6,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
          5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  7,  5,  7,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
          0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: Can you add small reproducible code.

Comment: @Bhupen I assume that a minimal reproducible code in this scenario will require a dataset to be really reproducible, which is unfortunately not obvious at the moment due to the large size of the dataset. I will update the question if I find the culprit row in the dataset.

Comment: When I'll find out what does line 92 exactly do It will be easier to identify the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After double checking the dataset and specifically the coordinates of the labels, I've found that some rows `bbox` coordinates lead to zero width or height. Here's a simplified example:

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 = dataset_row["bbox"]
print((x2-x1 < 1) or (y2-y1 < 1)) #output is sometimes True
```

After removing these labels from the dataset, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The more general problem is of breaking any of the criteria such as out of bounds of image.  Here is the code to remove any illegal boxes and associated words prior to passing the bboxes and words to the embeddings. It assumes you have two ordered lists, with normalized bounding boxes and associated words respectively. It may not be exhaustive.

Using tools such as PaddleOCR is more likely to produce these unconventional bounding boxes as the tool can return a wider variety of bounding boxes than PyTesseract e.g. when finding vertical text.

Boxes must be in x1,y1,x2,y2 format or top-left, bottom-right corners of the bounding box where (0,0) is top left corner of image.

**Note:**  One thing that caught me out before is that this means y coordinates must be inverted i.e. y = distance from top of image.

```
    for enum, box in enumerate(boxes_norm):
    if (
        box[0] >= box[2] # left coordinate actually on the right
        or box[1] >= box[3] # bottom coordinate actually on top
        or box[0] < 0 # off the page
        or box[1] < 0 # off the page
        or box[2] < 0 # off the page
        or box[3] < 0 # off the page
        or box[2] > 1000 # off the page
        or box[3] > 1000 # off the page
        or box[0] > 1000 # off the page
        or box[1] > 1000 # off the page
    ):
        # print(
        #     "removing invalid box and associated word from image - ",
        #     example["image_path"],
        # )
        # print("box - ", box)
        del boxes_norm[enum]
        del words[enum]
```